# Get device GPS / Location / coordinates in android studio

Tags: android, gps, android-location, android-gps, android-studio-2.3

I'm trying to get current device gps / location / coordinates of android device but its not working. I've tried some of solutions but they are still not working.
I'm using map in fragment and included that fragment in my main activity.
I'll be very thankful if someone give me a solution for my problem with some explaination to understand the working. I'm using android 4.4 and developing in studio 2.3.

Comment: show some code..so we can check for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android your answer is already in above link....

Comment: Do me a favor, can you give me a simple project of android studio having map in main activity using the fragment and getting current location / coordinates ?